# Can't get Project Euler #2

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler Problem #2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2)

This is what I wrote:

```
a = b = 1
i = []
while b <= 4000000:
    i.append(a)
    a, b = b, a + b
e = [x for x in i if not x % 2]
print(sum(e))
```

With this, I get `1089154`

However, if I replace the second last line with 
`e = [x for x in i if x % 2]`, I seem to get the right answer, `4613732`.

Why is this so, and what is wrong with what I originally wrote?

Comment: `x % 2` is 0 for even `x` and so these values are filtered out since 0 is falsey. It would be clearer to write: `[x for x in i if x % 2 == 0]`.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'filtered out'? BTW just tried `[x for x in i if x % 2 == 0]` and it returns 1089154.

Comment: are you asking what is the difference between `if` and `if not`? did you `print(e)`?

Comment: BTW: A slicker way to solve this problem that I'm compelled to point out every time someone asks about it. Look at the Fibonacci sequence and circle the even numbers. Do you see a pattern? Can you explain the pattern? Can you think of a way to make `b` (or `a`) take on that sequence of values directly, once per loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your list `i`. It starts with `[1, 1, 2, ...]` instead of `[1, 2, ...]`. Use `i.append(b)` to solve that problem.

Comment: This turns out to give the right answer, but for a misleading reason - since we are summing the even-*valued* terms, it doesn't matter that the list starts with an extra `1`. The problem is that because we test `b` for the loop bounds but append `a`, the last value of `3524578` doesn't make it into the list. The reason that the other sum - of the *odd* numbers - works is that, when a second `1` is included, these sums *necessarily are equal*. That happens because the sequence alternates two odd terms and an even term, and each even term is the sum of the two odd ones before it. :)